# The imageView in cells created by Xib will move a short distance when presented on screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNUy5.png)This problem confuses me for a long time. I create cells by xib, and use autolayout to set its position. There is an imageView in the cell, I set the leading,trailing,top bottom of the imageView, There is no warnings on the constraints.

However, when the tableview shows on the screen, there is no problem on iPhone6, but strange move on iPhone5s and 6P. **For 5s, the imageView shrink form 375 to 320; and for 6P, its width move from 375 to 414.** All the moves happened in less than 1 second, but  users can find it obviously.

I tried to change the width of xib from 375 to 320, and it comes out that the move disappeared on 5s,but showed on 6 and 6p.And when I change xib width from 375 to 414, the move shows on 5s and 6.

I don't know where the bug is, could anyone teach me, thank you so much!

Comment: Do you have a screenshot ?

Comment: Screenshot of your tableView and added constraints in storyboard would be helpful to find out the issue

Comment: I'm so sorry I mistake my problem. The move is not on the cell, but on the imageView in the cell. I have added the screenshot and there is no storyboard in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload the table at the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method of the view controller - reload it only if the width of the view of the view controller was changed.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    CGFloat width = self.view.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat e = 0.01;
    if (ABS(width - self.prevWidth) > e) {
        self.prevWidth = width;
        //reload table
    }
}
```

or in swift:

```
var prevWidth: CGFloat = 0

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let width = self.view.frame.width
    let e : CGFloat = 0.01

    if abs(width - self.prevWidth) > e {
        self.prevWidth = width
        //reload the table
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm sorry I mistake my problem and just now I reedited it. I will try your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Set constraints like : `leading,trailing,top,bottom` to cell. it may solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. just now I checked and found leading, trailing, top, bottom are all set.

Comment: then is it working? Only this four constraint should be there no more for cell like height or width constraint

Comment: it dosn't work, and I found the problem is not on the cell but on the imageview in the cell, you can see the image I added just now

Comment: Finally I found the problem. It is because that I wrote some code in
 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView  method, thus some conflicts appeared. After I delete the method, the bug disappeared.